# Could not transfer artifact. Trying to download from central repository instead of declared in pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a really small pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>my-nexus</id>
            <name>my-nexus</name>
            <url>https://nexus.mynexus.com/nexus/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>second-nexus</id>
            <name>second-nexus</name>
            <url>http://second-nexus.mynexus.com:8081/nexus/repo/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

however when I try to `mvn clean` I get error: `Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom` but why is it even looking for anything in central maven repository if I gave him two other nexuses from which artifacts should be taken?

Comment: configure the repository manager in your `settings.xml` file instead of the pom.xml file...  https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: @khmarbaise so everyone in project need to change `settings.xml` file? Is it not possible to override repositories in `pom.xml`? :O

Comment: So all of the devs have configured everything in pom files? Not a good idea...better to a single cleanup and configure that correctly into settings.xml and cleanup the configuration...and remove this infrastructure part from your pom file... also it can be configured correctly in your ci like Jenkins, Drone, whatever you use...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I am not sure if I understand correctly - the ideal world for me is that dev who create project (in this example me) can configure repos from which artifacts will be taken in `pom.xml` so the next dev just clone project `mvn clean install` and that's all. Why everyone need to change their settings.xml file to run this project? What if another dev will use another repositories in settings.xml? Again all team need to change settings.xml? I see much more disadvantages than advantages from this solution. When we configure it in pom.xml only one dev is involved, not whole team

Comment: In a corporate environment that does not make sense ...only a single repository manager should be used and not every dev should be able to simple use another repository from everywhere on the planet (all kinds of security implications etc)...furthermore why should a dev do `mvn clean install` ? Usually `mvn clean verify` is sufficient. A deployment to internal repository manager should be done by a CI solution.  also in a OSS world you should configure the needed repositories in settings.xml ...for example central does not allow to do to so... etc.

Comment: Furthermore what about if the name (dns entry) for the repo manager will change? So all old artifacts are now invalid and can not being built anymore! In the case of using settings.xml only this needs to be updated...that's it...